# Low impressions, high CTR for the same keywords with one difference - how to interpret?

Tags: google, advertising, google-ads

Let's say you're A/B testing book titles. All the book titles use the same metadata/description and keywords, but the only thing that changes is the title.

Why would you only get 1,000 impressions for one ad and 10,000 impressions for the second ad? It obviously has nothing to do with keywords/relevance, since both are the same?

Now let's say the 1,000 impression ad got a CTR of 15% and the 10,000 impression ad got a CTR of 7%. Which one is better? How would you interpret this, given that keywords/descriptions are all the same?

Comment: Before I answer, I want to clarify something that I am confused about.

You say that _"the only thing that changes is the title"_. Am I right to assume that you are using the book titles as (or in) the *headline* of your ads? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I yield to somebody trained in the art of marketing behavior, (but did not want your question go without an answer); I don't know if that is enough information for a solid conclusion; that said I feel the higher CTR is better; but with difficulty as:

CTR do not mean purchases, and CTR are driven by emotions which may just be because one title is more controversial than the other. And, the lower CTR may actually be qualifying the customer and have better sales.

If the offer is presented with other offers for other titles those would change the CTR. Somebody else may have an offer that appears with one but not both titles which grabbed the click through.

I hope I gave you some food for thought.